# first python: maze with backtracker

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

i'm learning python but i'm used to java development. this might have influenced my programming style.

feel free to give **any** feedback on the code

`maze_learning.py:`

```
import maze

def main():
    my_maze = maze.Maze(64, 64)
    my_maze.back_tracker()
    my_maze.print_maze()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`maze.py:`

```
import cell
import random


def pop(stack):
    item = stack[len(stack) - 1]
    del stack[len(stack) - 1]
    return item


def push(item, stack):
    size = len(stack)
    stack[size] = item


def add_if_unvisited(maze, pos, target):
    if pos in maze:
        current = maze[pos]
        if current.visited == 0:
            target.append(current)


def carve(from_cell, to_cell):
    if to_cell.x_pos - from_cell.x_pos == 1:
        from_cell.door_east = 1
        to_cell.door_west = 1
    if to_cell.x_pos - from_cell.x_pos == -1:
        from_cell.door_west = 1
        to_cell.door_east = 1
    if to_cell.y_pos - from_cell.y_pos == -1:
        from_cell.door_north = 1
        to_cell.door_south = 1
    if to_cell.y_pos - from_cell.y_pos == 1:
        from_cell.door_south = 1
        to_cell.door_north = 1


class Maze:
    width = 0
    height = 0
    cells = {}

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        for dy in range(0, height):
            for dx in range(0, width):
                self.cells[complex(dx, dy)] = cell.Cell(dx, dy)

    # see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm
    def back_tracker(self):
        stack = {}
        current = self.cells[complex(random.randint(0, self.width - 1), random.randint(0, self.height - 1))]
        current.visited = 1
        push(current, stack)
        while len(stack) > 0:
            current = pop(stack)
            unvisited = self.list_unvisited(current)
            if len(unvisited) > 0:
                push(current, stack)
                random_index = random.randint(0, len(unvisited) - 1)
                chosen = unvisited[random_index]
                carve(chosen, current)
                current = chosen
                current.visited = 1
                push(current, stack)

    def list_unvisited(self, current):
        pos_north = complex(current.x_pos, current.y_pos - 1)
        pos_east = complex(current.x_pos + 1, current.y_pos)
        pos_south = complex(current.x_pos, current.y_pos + 1)
        pos_west = complex(current.x_pos - 1, current.y_pos)

        neighbors = []
        add_if_unvisited(self.cells, pos_north, neighbors)
        add_if_unvisited(self.cells, pos_east, neighbors)
        add_if_unvisited(self.cells, pos_south, neighbors)
        add_if_unvisited(self.cells, pos_west, neighbors)
        return neighbors

    def print_maze(self):

        for dy in range(0, self.height):
            top_row = ""
            mid_row = ""
            bot_row = ""
            for dx in range(0, self.width):
                top_row = top_row + self.cells[complex(dx, dy)].top_row()
                mid_row = mid_row + self.cells[complex(dx, dy)].mid_row()
                bot_row = bot_row + self.cells[complex(dx, dy)].bot_row()
            print(top_row)
            print(mid_row)
            print(bot_row)
```

`cell.py:`

```
class Cell:
    door_north = 0
    door_east = 0
    door_west = 0
    door_south = 0
    visited = 0
    x_pos = 0
    y_pos = 0

    def __init__(self, xp, yp):
        self.x_pos = xp
        self.y_pos = yp

    def top_row(self):
        door = "###"
        if self.door_north == 1:
            door = "   "
        return "#" + door + "#"

    def mid_row(self):
        left_door = "#"
        if self.door_west == 1:
            left_door = " "
        right_door = "#"
        if self.door_east == 1:
            right_door = " "
        return left_door + "   " + right_door

    def bot_row(self):
        door = "###"
        if self.door_south == 1:
            door = "   "
        return "#" + door + "#"
```

this is, as said, my first code with python

Answer (score 1):

First some truth in advertising: I did not fully investigate the code and
assess everything. Basically I ran it and made various edits, ensuring that it
still worked after each of my changes. I sort of jumped around and stopped when
I ran out of energy. Perhaps someone else will consider the other aspects of the
program and provide more thorough feedback. For a first Python program, you're off
to a very good start.

**Declare attributes at the appropriate level**. Some Python programmers have a
habit of initializing instance-level attributes at the class level, rather than
in `__init__()`. They defend the practice under the it-works theory. Indeed it
does work, due to Python's lookup behavior: when it fails to find an attribute
on `self`, it turns to the class of `self`. However, from a code readability
perspective, it's an ill-advised shortcut. Your code is already quite readable,
so you should join Team Readability and declare instance-level attributes
inside of `__init__()`.

**Just use a tuple**. You have some dicts that appear to be
using `complex()` instances as a pragmatic, but somewhat sneaky, mechanism to carry
around two values (X and Y). Just use a tuple. Since tuples are hashable,
they can be used as dict keys. In terms of Python syntax, a tuple is created by
the comma operator, not the parentheses (the latter are used mainly for
readability and precedence). In your situation, that means a dict keyed by
tuple has a nice syntax: for example, `self.cells[dx, dy] = Cell(dx, dy)`.

**Just use a stack**. Based on variable naming, your algorithm in
`back_tracker()` claims to be using a stack, but it's not a stack; it's a dict.
As a result, you end up needing awkward push/pop mechanics where you're always
checking length, which leads you to write two unnecessary helper functions.
Just use a regular Python list, which behaves like a stack for your purposes of
pushing (append) and popping (pop).

**Python collections have sensible boolean behavior**. To check whether
a collection is empty, just evaluate it for truth: `while stack`. No
need to deal with length checks for such situations.

**Prefer collections over a proliferation of single variables**. In
`list_unvisited()`, you create 4 separate variables for each neighbor position.
Although those variables are well-named and serve a nice documentation
purpose, that fateful decision forces you to invent the
`add_if_unvisited()` utility function to perform the logic for each variable.
While it's good that you're not writing repetitive code, I think you'd be
better served by just creating a collection of positions and iterating over it
to build the list of valid neighbors. You can achieve the same readability
benefits of the 4 separate variable names via simple comments. However, even
better would be to define `Maze.NEIGHBOR_OFFSETS` and just iterate over those
offsets. Here's the idea:

```
class Maze:

    # A good use case for a class-level attribute.
    NEIGHBOR_OFFSETS = (
        (0, -1), # north
        (1, 0),  # east
        (0, 1),  # south
        (-1, 0), # west
    )

    def unvisited_neighbors(self, current):
        x, y = (current.x_pos, current.y_pos)
        neighbors = []
        for dx, dy in self.NEIGHBOR_OFFSETS:
            pos = (x + dx, y + dy)
            if pos in self.cells:
                current = self.cells[pos]
                if current.visited == 0:
                    neighbors.append(current)
        return neighbors
```

Comment: wow thank you very much - all things you told me were new to me doing **python**... Especially the mis-useage of the type (using `stack` instead of `dict`) since i simply do not know enough python to do it better! - and yes, thanks for the `NEIGHBOR_OFFSET`, i am used to use `enums` (or even a separate class) for that in java. i think i'll have to read about initialization on python as well!!!

Comment: https://readable.com/blog/joining-the-readable-io-team/ is this *"join Team Readability"*??

Comment: big wow effekt after adepting your changes - funny what is possible with python :-) thanks again!